# How to see the bandwidth usage of my Flash application?

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript, bandwidth

I'm developing an online sudoku game, with ActionScript 3.

I made the game and asked people to test it, it works, but the website goes down constantly. I'm using 000webhost, and I'm suspecting it is a bandwidth usage precaution.

My application updates the current puzzle, by parsing a JSON string every 2 seconds. And of course when players enter a number, it sends a $_GET request to update the mysql database. Do you think this causes a lot of data traffic?

How can I see the bandwidth usage value?

And how should I decrease the data traffic between Flash and mysql (or php, really).

Thanks !

Comment: Firbug or the chrome console let you view the network usage of your page. In order to decrease traffic, you should just exchange what is needed. I honestly don't see why you need to exchange data with the server during a Sudoku game though....

Comment: @Bartdude Thanks, I tried the Chrome Developer Tools but couldn't find the data. I need to update because all users simultaneously solve a single puzzle, and the state of puzzle needs to be updated.

Comment: there's a "network" tab in chrome developer tools. once opened, you may need to refresh the page though. I personnally prefer firebug though, less complete but I find it easier to use. You can also use a tool like fiddler to intercept http requests.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information for a straight answer, and if there were, it'd probably take more time to figure out. But here's some directions you could look into.

Bandwidth may or may not be an issue. There are many things that could happen, you may very well put too much strain on the HTTP server, run out of worker threads, have your MySQL tables lock up most of the time, etc.

What you're doing indeed sounds like it's putting a lot of strain on the server. Monitoring this client side could be inefficient, you need to look at some server-side values, but you generally don't have access to those unless you have at least a VPS.

Transmitting data as JSONs is easier to implement and debug, but a more efficient way to send data (binary, instead of strings) is AMF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format
One PHP implementation for the server side part is AMFPHP: http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/

Alternatively, your example is a good use case for the remote shared objects in Flash Media Server (or similar products). A remote shared object is exactly what you're doing with MySQL: it creates a common memory space where you can store whatever data and it keeps that data synchronised with all the clients. Automagically. :)
You can start from here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/hpdocs/help.html?content=00000100.html